# How to separate overlapping blobs?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, object-detection

I'm doing a uni project where I have to detect the number of structural elements in a picture. My aim is to create a blob for each element so that I can then count them.

So far I did this little bit of coding attached. The problem is that often the objects are overlapping (see bottom left part with 4 attached elements forming a single blob). How can I bypass this problem? I genuinely do not know how to solve this.

```
% Read the image and convert to L*a*b* color space
I = imread('Crop.jpg');
Ilab = rgb2lab(I);
% Extract a* and b* channels and reshape
ab = double(Ilab(:,:,2:3));
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);
% Segmentation usign k-means
nColors = 4;
[cluster_idx, cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,...
'distance',     'sqEuclidean', ...
'Replicates',   3);
% Show the result
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
figure(1);
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');
```

***Crop.jpg***:
[image: Crop.jpg]

EDIT: I also thought that some kind of object detection algorithm could do the trick but the elements change in orientation too besides overlapping. I saw this video tutorial [Object and feature detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddXvs1Wp95A&t=810s), but I can't read the code for the centroid at around 10:58 so I can't try it myself. Do you think this could work? Thanks again.

Comment: since all your objects have roughly the same size (i.e., appearing in same scale in the image) you can get a rough estimate of segment size (in pixels) and then for too large segments, estimate the number of objects by dividing the blob size with the average object size.

Comment: Yes that could be a way. I was thinking about creating a segment after the pixel_labels picture pops out, something like:
h = ginput(2);
Dmax = sqrt((h(2)-h(1))^2+(h(4)-h(3))^2);
meanBlobArea = 3.14*(Dmax^2)/4;

but then how (coding) can I access to the blobs areas values and create a loop where I use the meanBlobArea to exclude blobs with dimensions bigger and smaller than that, then count those that make the cut? Thanks

Comment: (1) look at `regionprops` command and `bwlabel` to get sizes of blobs. (2) you might want to look at `median` area rather than `mean`: it is more robust to outliers.

Comment: Yes I have a similar code by SimpleColorDetectionByHue() that uses both regionprops and bwlabel, but I'm not able to adjust it to my problem. I don't have the skills. I can't post code too because the comment will be too long.

Comment: you may edit your question or ask a new one if it is not overlap too.much with this one.